# update with sub query successful but not updating

Tags: sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have wrong duplicate id loaded in the table and we need to correct it.
The rules to update the id is whenever there is a time difference of more than 30 min, the id should be new/unique.
I have written the query to filter that out, however update is not happening

The below query is there to find the ids to be updated.
For testing I have used a particular id.

```
select id,
       BEFORE_TIME,
       TIMESTAMP,
       datediff(minute,BEFORE_TIME,TIMESTAMP) time_diff,
       row_number() over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) rowno,
       concat(id,to_varchar(rowno)) newid from
            (SELECT id, 
                    TIMESTAMP,
                    LAG(TIMESTAMP_EST) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) as BEFORE_TIME
                FROM table_name t
                where id = 'XX1X2375'
                order by TIMESTAMP_EST)
         where BEFORE_TIME is not NULL and time_diff > 30
       order by time_diff desc
       ;
```

And i could see the 12 record with same id and time difference more than 30.
However when I am trying to update. the query is succesfull but nothing is getting update.

```
update table_name t
set t.id = c.newid
from 
(select id ,
       BEFORE_TIME,
       TIMESTAMP,
       datediff(minute,BEFORE_TIME,TIMESTAMP) time_diff,
       row_number() over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) rowno,
       concat(id,to_varchar(rowno)) newid from
            (SELECT id, 
                    TIMESTAMP,
                    LAG(TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) as BEFORE_TIME
                FROM table_name t
                where id = 'XX1X2375'
                order by TIMESTAMP_EST)
         where BEFORE_TIME is not NULL and time_diff > 30
       order by time_diff desc) c
where t.id = c.id
  and t.timestamp = c.BEFORE_TIME       
       ;
```

Comment: snowflake. could you please forward an oracle query, but it is based on oracle

Comment: Any help please